# What are the details of this PySpark column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In attempting to understand PySpark constructs this code :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions struct
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
F.struct(lit(10).alias("column") , "TEST").desc()
```

creates a column with value :

```
Column<struct(10 AS `columnee`, TEST) DESC>
```

What are the details of this column ? `F.struct` is creating a column with value 10 and column header "column" with rowname "TEST" ?

If use :

```
F.struct(lit(10).alias("column") , "TEST")
```

creates :

```
Column<struct(10 AS `column`, TEST)>
```

So `DESC` is now removed. Is `DESC` added as a function to be evaluated when the column is evaluated ?

Comment: can you share reproducible example? what are you trying to do?

Comment: @mtoto i've updated question with import statements, but I'm just attempting to find a more elaborate explanation for  `F.struct(lit(10).alias("column") , "TEST").desc() ` as I find the PySpark API a little cryptic